# I have a Type D France (sauf CTOM) spouse visa. Can I land at Basel Euroairport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, france, basel

If my interpretation is correct, then with this visa I cannot transit through any other Schengen countries as my point of entry needs to be France. Is that correct? 
Also, Can I enter through Basel airport? What I mean is, will the immigration authorities be representing France or Switzerland?

Comment: By transit I mean, can I get a flight with a layover at Amsterdam or Frankfurt?

Comment: You should edit that information into your question rather than posting it as a comment.

Comment: "will the immigration authorities be representing France or Switzerland?" they will be representing the external border of Schengen area.

Comment: It's been too long since I last went there to remember the process and layout in details and there have been many changes over the years but note that (1) the airport is built entirely on French territory and (2) both border forces are present. I cannot imagine that someone with a valid French visa could be prevented from entering the country.

Comment: @kiradotee That's dodging the question. Even within the Schengen framework, every border guard is a national border guard, every Schengen stamp mentions a country, etc. Can you choose if you get to talk to a Swiss or a French border guard? Do they rotate depending on availability? Are all checks happening under the authority of the French state?

Answer (score 6):

> with this visa I cannot transit through any other Schengen countries as my point of entry needs to be France. Is that correct?

No.  You can transit through any Schengen country or countries on your way to France.  This is explicit in the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407).

Article 6(5)(a):

> 5. By way of derogation from paragraph 1:
>      (a) third-country nationals who do not fulfil all the conditions laid down in paragraph 1 but who hold a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall be authorised to enter the territory of the other Member States for transit purposes so that they may reach the territory of the Member State which issued the residence permit or the long-stay visa, unless their names are on the national list of alerts of the Member State whose external borders they are seeking to cross and the alert is accompanied by instructions to refuse entry or transit;

This means that if you do not meet the requirements of paragraph 1 then you will be allowed to transit to France unless there is an alert in the system preventing you from doing so.  If you *do* fulfill the conditions in paragraph one then you can even visit other Schengen countries *for up to 90 days* before setting foot in France.

> Can I enter through Basel airport?

Yes.

> What I mean is, will the immigration authorities be representing France or Switzerland?

It doesn't matter.

In a comment, you ask

> By transit I mean, can I get a flight with a layover at Amsterdam or Frankfurt?

Yes.  If you do that, you'll clear immigration controls in Amsterdam or Frankfurt rather than Switzerland or France, but as outlined above that is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks phone for your response. So you're saying that I can enter France by road if I land in Zurich? My visa explicitly says that's its valid for "France (Saul CTOM)" and not Schengen states.

Comment: @Nina D visas always list only the country that has issued the visa, but D visas are nonetheless valid for travel to any Schengen state.  You can land in Zurich, Frankfurt, Vienna, Madrid, Milan, etc., etc., and travel to France by air, rail, road, or any other means.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Basel Euroairport is a two country airport, located in France, depending on the exit (for immigration and custom, you enter in France or in Switzerland.

See the [Euroairpot FAQ](https://www.euroairport.com/en/faq/common-questions.html#faq_108624)

> Are there multiple exits for arriving passengers (France / Switzerland)?
>
> Yes; the airport consists of two separate parts, a French part and a Swiss part.
> Arriving passengers can choose freely if they want to leave the baggage claim area for France or for Switzerland. The respective exits are clearly marked.

Comment: But to get to the baggage claim area, passengers will have to clear immigration controls.  Are those immigration officers Swiss or French?